# VBS to address file on desktop

Tags: vbscript, desktop

I am a VBS noob so forgive the simple question. I have created a script to open an .xlsx document on my desktop, and run various actions. I would like to port the script to other users. That said, how can I create a path that will work for all users, i.e. a user desktop variable. In PowerShell I could do `'$env:USERPROFILE + '\Desktop''` and it would address the current user's desktop. Is there a VBS equivalent?

What I have so far:

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
xl.Application.Visible = True

Dim wb1
Set wb1 = xl.Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Missed_Scans\Reports\Report.xlsx")
Dim wb2
Set wb2 = xl.Workbooks.Add

wb1.Sheets("Incomplete_ASINs").Range("$A$1:$J$52951").AutoFilter 1, "SDF8"
wb1.Sheets("Incomplete_ASINs").Columns("B:D").Copy
wb2.Worksheets(1).Paste
wb2.Worksheets(1).Rows(1).AutoFilter
wb2.SaveAs "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Missed_Scans\Reports\Missed_Scans.xlsx", 51, , , , False
wb2.Close
wb1.Close False
xl.Quit
Set xl = Nothing
```

Lines 5 and 13 are the areas that need to use some type of user environment variable. I understand that `environ("UserName")` can provide the username, but I am not sure how to incorporate it.

Comment: What you are looking for is CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(SpecialFolderName). The following special folders are available: AllUsersDesktop, AllUsersStartMenu, AllUsersPrograms, AllUsersStartup, Desktop, Favorites, Fonts, MyDocuments, NetHood, PrintHood, Programs, Recent, SendTo, StartMenu, Startup, Templates.

Comment: @RegisDesrosiers: You should write that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [ExpandEnvironmentStrings](https://ss64.com/vb/envexpand.html):

```
Set osh = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
xl.workbooks.open osh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%userprofile%\Desktop\Missed_Scans\Reports\Report.xlsx")
```

For line 13 also, you can write something like:

```
wb2.SaveAs osh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%userprofile%\Desktop\Missed_Scans\Reports\Missed_Scans.xlsx"), 51, , , , False
```

**Update:**

Note: I did not make any changes to any logic. Just removed the errors.

```
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
xl.Application.Visible = True

Dim wb1
Set osh = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
Set wb1 = xl.Workbooks.Open(osh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%userprofile%\Desktop\Missed_Scans\Reports\Report.xlsx"))
Dim wb2
Set wb2 = xl.Workbooks.Add

wb1.Sheets("Incomplete_ASINs").Range("$A$1:$J$52951").AutoFilter 1, "SDF8"
wb1.Sheets("Incomplete_ASINs").Columns("B:D").Copy
wb2.Worksheets(1).Paste
wb2.Worksheets(1).Rows(1).AutoFilter
wb2.SaveAs osh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%userprofile%\Desktop\Missed_Scans\Reports\Missed_Scans.xlsx"), 51, , , , False
wb2.Close
wb1.Close False
xl.Quit
Set xl = Nothing
```

Comment: Hi @Gurman , I am trying out your ideas but I am not having success. It seems to open the doc correctly but the rest of my script doesnt work. Could you please repost the entire script with your additions? I may have left something or missed something.

Comment: Okay. I thought your main issue was generalizing the path for different userprofiles to the open the excel and I had posted the solution for that. What exactly is the error that you are getting?

Comment: The vbs script is being run thru Powershell so i get a PS Error: Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: '' 

With your recommendations the vbs script opens the document 'report.xlsx' but it is not doing the rest of the steps (filter col, copy and paste and add filters, then close w/o prompt).

Comment: Perfecto! Thanks for the help.